# Getting repository contents using GitHub API

Tags: github-api, octokit

I know there is an API for getting repository content. But my use case is I need to get the whole repository and display it in my UI like GitHub UI. Similar to GitHub UI, I need my repository to be displayed in my UI. Is there any API I can use to get the whole repository so I can display that in my UI.

I tried this API.

```
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/zipball/REF
```

But it gives separate file contents. I need the whole repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the all repository remains easier with a simple [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone). No need for an API call there.

If, as mentioned in this [2016 octokit issue](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/issues/1066#issuecomment-175310923), you cannot clone through GitHub API, you could use [libgit2sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) to integrate the clone operation in your application.

Comment: Is there a way I can get the contents of repo and display that repo structure in my UI as same as Github UI?

Comment: @KaranS It depends on the nature of your UI. I use [Gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/) as a GitHub-like web service..